# XMLHttpRequest "history" - getting a previous request

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

This one is a little strange.  I have a page that makes several ajax calls (using jQuery $.ajax).

The later requests are dependent on the results of previous ones, but for reasons of design I cannot change, they aren't nested together in proper success/error callbacks.  So, the downwind calls break nastily if there predecessors fail.

Browser debugging tools like Firebug show me a list of all the ajax calls the page makes, and you can of course inspect them, look at the post and response, etc.

Is there a way to access that list of "previous requests" programatically?  For example, I wanna look at the previous request from the xmlhttp 'history' stack the debugging tools seem to be reading, and access the properties of a specific request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found a suitable answer to this, so found the time to refactor the pages with the issues.